# Saving the dataframe to to csv/xls without the prompt - Do you want to allow read-write access to:

Tags: python, excel, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, prompt

I am trying to save a dataframe in csv/xls format.
I want to automate/avoid the allow prompt altogether.

I am getting the below prompt, as soon as I execute the code:

```
 allocation.to_csv(r'\Users\Ritwick\rets_df.csv')
```

[The Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPAXt.jpg)

I tried:

a)

```
if df_c.to_csv(r'\Users\Ritwick\rets_df.csv').confirm('Do you want to allow read-write access to:'):
    click.echo('Allow')
```

b)

```
with open("/Users/Ritwick/rets_df.csv", "w+") as fh:
    fh.write(p1)
os.chmod("/Users/Ritwick/rets_df.csv", 0o777)
```

None worked for me.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes.
```
import pandas as pd,
import numpy as np,
from collections import OrderedDict,
from scipy.stats import norm,
from scipy.stats import rankdata,
import math,
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as dt,
```

Comment: your prompt doesn't match your code because in the prompt it says C:\Users\Ritwick\PythonExport.xls but in the code you're trying to save to this file => \Users\Ritwick\rets_df.csv. Can we see more code?

Comment: @Tyger - I tried doing that also. It is giving me the same prompt.

Comment: It would be helpful to elaborate on what kind of environment you're in. It's unclear where that dialog is coming from but it's not a standard Pandas or Python thing. Are you running in some sort of server environment (e.g. Anaconda Enterprise) or have a very locked down by IT system?

Comment: @Igaud - It's in Bloomberg's BQNT platform server, which uses Jupyter Notebook environment. So I can do anything, which I can do in an Acanconda -  Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: You should probably look at documentation for BQNT or ask their support. There's something in that environment interfering with saving files in general. This has nothing to do with the tags you've specified.